# How to SELECT inside UPDATE in a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, mysql-8.0

Multiples posts asking about it already exist, solutions have been given and they worked for my previous queries.
But it won't work now that I try the same query to SELECT inside an UPDATE from the same table.

Here are the differents queries I tried :

```
UPDATE usersDB.random
SET total_partners =
(
SELECT total_partners FROM usersDB.random
WHERE year = 2022
)
WHERE uid = 1
```

and

```
UPDATE usersDB.random
SET total_partners = 
(
SELECT total_partners
FROM usersDB.random
AS x
WHERE year = 2022
)
WHERE uid = 1
```

But I get this error message everytime :

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'random' for update
> in FROM clause

The same query but with two differents table work tho :

```
UPDATE usersDB.random
SET total_partners =
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM usersDB.partners AS x
)
WHERE (month = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) and year = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) OR uid = 1
```

How can I make it work when it's the same table ? Version of Mysql is 8.0

Here is how the table `random` looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Brl.png

I use Mysql Workbench to send the queries

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure how to provide a reproducible example as you'd need to create the schema, the tables etc. This is why I provided a working query that is only very slightly different to the one not working. I thought that would be enough.

Comment: Can you show your table structure cause in general all above queries seems OK

Comment: Hence my comment

Comment: @IdleJatt I provided a screenshot of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not provide a simple test data `Create Table/Insert Into (copypaste text)` script I had to experiment with my own table scheme. See this with `aTemp` temporary table how I use two-level inner table.

```
Update person Set 
city=(
 Select Concat(now(),"-",aTemp.val1) from
 (select count(*) as val1 from person) as aTemp
)
Where id=4
```

So out of my mind it may translate to this query.

```
UPDATE usersDB.random
SET total_partners=(
 Select aTemp.val1 From
 (SELECT count(*) as val1 FROM usersDB.random WHERE year=2022) aTemp
)
WHERE uid = 1
```